# Return multiple instances of SSRS report on one execution

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, instance, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that is mostly static text, with a small 1x5 tablix with address info, a list with two expressions and a data set field on it.  Currently, it returns the address, forwarding address and order number for a particular order.

I want to be able to select multiple order #s, but for each order #, i want an individually printed report.  I selected multiple values for the parameter, and can populate the list with a query that returns all order #s.  However, when the user selects multiple orders, it crams all the order addresses into the same spot on ONE instance of the report.  i would like a new page for each order #.

Let me know if you need any further info (dataset, query, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can place your current report inside a rectangle that you group on order number. Then simply adjust the `PageBreak` property of the rectangle.

Comment: how do you group a rectangle? i don't see that function in the properties

Comment: should i use a list instead?

Comment: List is actually the same as a rectangle. When you use a list it'll actually become a rectangle, this is similar to when you add a table and it becomes a tablix.

Comment: ah, got ya.  so how do i set the group on property? not seeing it in therectangle's properties

Comment: You have to group your dataset  before you send it to the report. Or wrap the rectangle inside another 1x1 tablix, this will allow you to do a RowGroup. But if your dataset is set up correctly, you might not even have to group at all, it depends on your dataset really.You basically just want the reporter to create a single rectangle for each order number.